# Import of CSV files that do not have a txt OR csv extenion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, csv, openrowset

My goal is to have a file (it comes from another system) that I want to import via an **OPENROWSET** style query.

Tee query would look like this:

```
select [NoName]  from openrowset('MSDASQL'
           ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};
                DefaultDir=c:\filedir'
           ,'select * from "file.lst"')
```

If I make the file a **.csv** it works fine.  However, if it has a not CSV or TXT extension it throws the following error and cannot seem to find a solution to it.

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".
```

In addition, (although I can probably find this elsewhere), I need to have the first line **'BLANK'** so that it does not miss data (there is no header row).  Is there  a way to use **OPENROWSET** without **BULK** to basically include all rows as data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [security *feature*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245407/en-us) which can only be disabled in your registry. By default only the following file extensions are allowed: `txt, csv, tab, asc, htm, html`

**Access 97:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Jet\3.5\Engines\Text\DisabledExtensions
```

**Access 2000:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\DisabledExtensions
```